# ASP MVC 6: sending multiselectselect as POST

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view in my app, that allows user to set up 2 multiselects.
The problem is: how can I send contents of those multiselects back to controller.
So far I have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div id="member-list">
        <div class="row" id="transfer">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select multiple="multiple" id="right-select">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.AnotherContacts)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.Id" onclick="transfer(this)">
                            @item.Email - @item.Name
                        </option>
                    }
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select multiple="multiple" id="left-select">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Group.Members)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.Contact.Id" onclick="transfer(this)">
                            @item.Contact.Email -  @item.Contact.Name
                        </option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-grey" value="Save" />
        </div>

    </div>
```

And now: how to write a controller to have there list of items, hat I have in both multiselects?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Manage(int id)
    {


        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first for a form post to be successful you need to add name attributes to your inputs.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="left-select" name="leftSelect">
<select multiple="multiple" id="right-select" name="rightSelect">
```

Then your controller would be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage(int[] leftSelect, int[] rightSelect)
{
    //your code

    return View();
}
```

Notice the names of method parameters are the same as the name attributes on the select lists.

> Note: I assumed your `@item.Contact.Id` and `@item.Id` are of type
>   int.

Comment: Fine, this works perfectly, but is there any possibility to get ALL items from list, not only selected ones?

Comment: To get all items add a hidden field using  :`@Html.HiddenFor` if using razor or ` <input type="hidden" id="hdnCompleteList" value="yourvalue"/> ` and add parameter in your action method with the same name

Comment: The way you have your view set up would suggest the values are coming from the server side. If they are stored in a DB could you not retrieve the values again? Unless the client side is adding additional values.

Comment: Well as long as they are not adding, you should still be able to compare against the original values from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Make your controller expect several parameters

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage(int id, int id2)
{
    //your code

    return View();
}
```

This of course depends on what you want to send to to the controller, but I hope you get the idea. You havent shown the code required, but I would guess you have selectLists that return strings, and if that is the case, change the parameters in the Manage Action to expect string variables

Comment: But what are those IDs? I don't know how many items there will be in each multiselect

Comment: Oh, then you will have more work ahead.. you will need to create overloads of your Action to handle different number of parameters or make some parameters optional. I changed my answer a little with more explanation under. You should give a bit more code so that it is easier to find the part that is flawed

Comment: The id´s i presented in the code are often the index number of an item or a chosen row in a list, so if you are sending information from more than one list to a Method, you need to send the method a way to know what that information is